# Firestore onRemove not called when document meets condition

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an expire condition, like snapchat, when the expire time is met then to remove the document from the query, but it doesn't work until the app is reloaded or closed the open, not in realtime.

Code:

```
Services().crud.readStream(
    stream: this
        .collection
        .where('user', isEqualTo: APIs().users.collection.document(cUserID))
        .where('removeAt', isGreaterThan: Timestamp.now())
        .snapshots(),
    onEmpty: () {
      onEmpty(null);
    },
    onAdded: (p) {
      onAdded(Post().model(id: p.documentID, map: p.data));
      return null;
    },
    onModified: (p) {
      onModified(Post().model(id: p.documentID, map: p.data));
      return null;
    },
    onRemoved: (p) {
      onRemoved(Post().model(id: p.documentID, map: p.data));
      return null;
    },
    onFailure: (e) {
      onFailure(e);
      return null;
    });
```

The thing is that it works, just not in realtime. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from this line:

```
.where('removeAt', isGreaterThan: Timestamp.now())
```

This is evaluated when you run the query, and that means that `Timestamp.now()` is set when the query starts. So it will get the documents that are not expired when you start the query, but it won't dynamically update while the listener is active (since `Timestamp.now()` doesn't get reevaluated).

There is (currently) no way to have a dynamically updating timestamp in a Firestore query. But luckily you have all the information to implement the dynamic expiration yourself in the client. Since you know the value of `removeAt` for each document, you can run a periodic check, and remove or hide the documents that have expired while your snapshot listener was active.